# Continuously subtracting- Python 3.X

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a tuple like:

```
mytuple = (10,10)
mylist = []
mylist.append(mytuple)
```

I would like to subtract 1 from each iteration of x in mytuple until there is only 0 so that mylist would look like

```
[(10,10),(9,10),(8,10),(7,10),etc.,(0,10)]
```

I was thinking about a for loop, but I couldn't really figure out how to get this output. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

range lets you specify the step taken with your iteration, which lets you do something like this:

```
mytuple = (10,10)
mylist = []
for i in range(mytuple[0], -1, -1):
    mylist.append((i, mytuple[1]))
print(mylist)
```

See this in action here: http://ideone.com/wnM5zb

Answer (score 1):

```
mytuple = (10,10)
mylist = []
mylist.append(mytuple)
# store mytuple's first value
val = mytuple[0] 

# while val is greater than 0
while (val > 0):
    # subtract 1 from val
    val -= 1
    # generate tuple and add to list
    mylist.append((val,10))
print(mylist)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
mytuple = (10,10)
mylist = [(i,mytuple[1]) for i in range(mytuple[0],-1,-1)]
```